# many-to-many instead of one-to-many

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

I'm little confused why JPA creates two many-to-many instead of 2 one-to-many relationships.
I have class author and two Set collection of phones and emails.

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Phone> phones;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Email> emails;
```

and two classes

```
@Entity
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_phone_id")
    private Author author;

@Entity
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_id")
    private Author author;
```

So JPA should create Author, Phone, Email tables, but JPA additionally creates author_email, author_phone tables. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JPA provider creates additional tables (`author_email` and `author_phone`) because you have bidirectional relationships but you didn't point out which side of those relationships are owners (`mappedBy` attribute).

Make the following changes regarding collections in `Author` class and it should work as you expected.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "author")
private Set<Phone> phones;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "author")
private Set<Email> emails;
```